# How do I expand multiple cards in react with state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css

I have a list of cards. After click on each card I want them to expand with little bit more info. I get the cards from the server and map them. To expand single card, not multiple, I've created a state editIndex which checks the id of the card so it could work correctly and expand specifically that card. I can't figure out, how do I expand one card and other at the same time. Because right now if I click on card, the other one which was expanded is collapsing.

```
  const [studentList, setStudentList] = useState();
  const [input, setInput] = useState(" ");
  const [editIndex, setEditIndex] = useState(null);
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState(null);


 const handleExpand = (id) => {
 setEditIndex((e) => (e === id ? null : id))};
 
return (
<div
  className="flex
  flex-col 
  w-4/5
  h-[800px]
  overflow-scroll
  scrollbar-hide
  border 
  bg-white 
  rounded-xl
  "
>
  <div>
    {studentList?.map(
      ({
        city,
        company,
        email,
        firstName,
        grades,
        id,
        lastName,
        pic,
        skill,
      }) => (
        <div
          key={uuidv4()}
          onClick={(e) => handleExpand(id)}
          className="flex  border-b-2 py-2 px-7 xl:px-12 cursor-pointer
            mb-2 max-h-96 transition transform ease duration-200;
            "
        >
          <div className="flex items-center ">
            <img
              src={pic}
              className="flex items-center border rounded-full object-cover w-  [100px] h-[100px]"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="ml-10 superTest ">
            <p className="font-bold text-4xl">
              {firstName} {lastName}
            </p>
            <p>E-mail: {email}</p>
            <p>Company: {company}</p>
            <p>Skill: {skill}</p>
            <p>Average: {grades}% </p>

            {editIndex === id && (
              <div>
                <p>1</p>
                <p>2</p>
                <p>3</p>
                <p>4</p>
                <p>5</p>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    )}
  </div>
</div>
  );
    }

 export default Card;
```

Comment: Another simple solution is that you create a separate component (e.g. `StudentCard`) that renders a single student card. Then you can have a state (open/closed) inside every student card.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `editIndex`, have a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of the `id` values of expanded cards:

```
const [editing, setEditing] = useState(new Set());
```

Then, to expand/contract a card (sadly, `Set` has no built-in `toggle` method):

```
const handleExpand = (id) => {
    setEditing(editing => {
        // Copy the set
        editing = new Set(editing);
        if (editing.has(id)) {
            // Already editing, stop editing
            editing.delete(id);
        } else {
            // Not editing, start
            editing.add(id);
        }
        return editing;
    });
};
```

To determine whether a card is expanded, it's `editing.has(id)`:

```
{editing.has(id) && (
  <div>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
  </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an array or map of expanded cards:

```
const [editIndex, setEditIndex] = useState([]);
...
const handleExpand = (id) => {
  setEditIndex((e) => (e.includes(id) ? e.filter(i => i !== id) : [...e, id]))
};
...
{editIndex.includes(id) && (
          <div>
            <p>1</p>
            <p>2</p>
            <p>3</p>
            <p>4</p>
            <p>5</p>
          </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should state with an object and keep expanded card ids in the object. Using object instead of an array you avoid loop to filter the array

```
  import React, { useState } from 'react';
  
  function Card() {
    const [studentList, setStudentList] = useState();
    const [editIndex, setEditIndex] = useState({});

    const handleExpand = (id) => {
        setEditIndex((e) => (e === id ? null : id))
        setEditIndex({id: !editIndex[id]});
    };

    return studentList.map((student, index) => 
        <div onClick={() => handleExpand(index)} className={`otherClassNames ${editIndex[index]?"expanded":"collapsed"}`}>
            {JSON.stringify(student)} // render student data
        </div>
        );
  }
  
  export default Card;
```

On the other hand, you can use the Collapse component of the Ant Design library. So leave the collapse issue them.

https://ant.design/components/collapse/

and other complicated components are available in the library use should check out.